# renaming a file by adding current date

Tags: file, renaming

I'm working on a Project and a Part of it is renaming a File to "Filename + currentDate". I have been searching for an answer and found some helpful Topics on that Problem, but i still didn't get my code to work properly(or do anything at all).

Here is my code:

```
File oldTxt = new File("Filename.txt");
GregorianCalendar now = new GregorianCalendar(); 
DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.SHORT); 
String archivedName = "Filename"+ 
String.valueOf(dateFormat.format(now.getTime())).replace(".", "_")+".txt";
File archivedTxt = new File(archivedName);
oldTxt.renameTo(archivedTxt);
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed the line to create new file.

> oldTxt.createNewFile();

```
    File oldTxt = new File("Filename.txt");
-->    oldTxt.createNewFile();
    GregorianCalendar now = new GregorianCalendar(); 
    DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.SHORT); 
    String archivedName = "Filename"+ 
    String.valueOf(dateFormat.format(now.getTime())).replace(".", "_")+".txt";
    File archivedTxt = new File(archivedName);
    oldTxt.renameTo(archivedTxt);
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer. I already created the old File in another Task. Do I still have to create it again?

Comment: Your using the file object oldTxt fo renamig so it must point to a file or you have to use the same object you created in another task.